# How to add small window into Form

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Dockable autohiding panel control for Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766336/dockable-autohiding-panel-control-for-windows-forms)

I have a problem. I don't know how to make "small window" in a Form. I mark them on the picture. They are panels or what? How to add close, minimize etc. Buttons to them and allow to move them?

[image: picture]

Comment: Do you need the tool windows to be dockable/floatable as well?

Answer (score 3):

Check out this third party Docking Panel control. ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/ )

You use it to create DockingWindow type forms which can then automatically dock/fill/float on your main form which has a docking container. The layout of all docked windows within that docking container then serialise nicely to XML which can be stored however you need, in order to reload the form later.

Answer (score 2):

Those are called Dock Panels.. and do not exist in the BCL.  You will have to find a 3rd party component developer or make some yourself.